# Custom payment processor for credit balance - need ideas and advice

Tags: payment-processor

Our organization maintains a "deposit account" or "credit account" for our constituents. Account balance info is stored in a 3rd party MS SQL application.

I would like to hear high-level ideas and advice on how go about building a custom payment processor so that folks can pay for CiviEvent fees, etc., using their credit account balance.

Has anyone encountered this situation before?

Comment: How does it check their balance? Do you record that somewhere? Or is it just a book keeping entry?

Answer (score 1):

I would try grabbing the code for one of the current payment processors and creating a new instance of it for your credit account "processor".  This should give you the plumbing necessary for CiviCRM; of course you will still need to build out the interface with the MSSQL application, but you will need to do that anyway.

To start this, do a 30 minute dive into the current civi payment processors... I recall there being some fairly simple implementations that you probably can most easily leverage.